# Erro "Column not found" em SELECT via JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou tentando fazer uma simples consulta em java usando o operador do SQL "Union" para unir duas consultas em uma, porém não estou obtendo sucesso.

Erro: Column 'ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL' not found.

Ambiente: Java JDBC, MYSQL.

Testes feitos:

- Funciona quando eu copio o SQL gerado e colo no MYSQL Worbench
- Quando eu retiro a segunda consulta, ou seja, uma consulta normal sem o union, funciona normalmente.
- Se eu tiro a coluna ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL do SELECT e de todas as linhas onde ela é chamada ele passa a dar erro na próxima.

Código usado:

```
public ArrayList<OrdemServico> relatorioDeVendas(String deInicio, String ateInicio, String deFechamento, String ateFechamento) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = ConexaoBanco.getConexao();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT \n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.ID_PROJETO,\n"
                + " ADICIONAIS.NUMERO,\n"
                + " CLIENTE.NOMEFANTASIA,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.NOME,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDIRETO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDOLPHIN,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALOR_COMISSAO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.PRIORIDADE,\n"
                + " STATUS.NOME,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATASOLICITACAO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAINICIO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAPREVENTREGA,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAENTREGA,\n"
                + " PESSOA.NOME\n"
                + "FROM ORDEMSERVICO \n"
                + "INNER JOIN PROJETOS ON ORDEMSERVICO.ID_PROJETO = PROJETOS.ID\n"
                + "INNER JOIN ADICIONAIS ON ORDEMSERVICO.ID_ADICIONAL = ADICIONAIS.ID\n"
                + "INNER JOIN CLIENTE ON ORDEMSERVICO.FK_CODCLIENTE = CLIENTE.CODCLIENTE\n"
                + "INNER JOIN STATUS ON ORDEMSERVICO.CODSTATUS = STATUS.CODSTATUS\n"
                + "INNER JOIN PESSOA ON ORDEMSERVICO.RESPONSAVEL = PESSOA.CODPESSOA\n"
                + "WHERE ORDEMSERVICO.DATAINICIO BETWEEN ('"+deInicio+"') AND ('"+ateInicio+"')\n"
                + "AND PRINCIPAL = TRUE AND CODTIPOOS = 21\n"
                + " UNION \n"
                + "SELECT \n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.ID_PROJETO,\n"
                + " ADICIONAIS.NUMERO,\n"
                + " CLIENTE.NOMEFANTASIA,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.NOME,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDIRETO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDOLPHIN,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.VALOR_COMISSAO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.PRIORIDADE,\n"
                + " STATUS.NOME,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATASOLICITACAO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAINICIO,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAPREVENTREGA,\n"
                + " ORDEMSERVICO.DATAENTREGA,\n"
                + " PESSOA.NOME\n"
                + "FROM ORDEMSERVICO \n"
                + "INNER JOIN PROJETOS ON ORDEMSERVICO.ID_PROJETO = PROJETOS.ID\n"
                + "INNER JOIN ADICIONAIS ON ORDEMSERVICO.ID_ADICIONAL = ADICIONAIS.ID\n"
                + "INNER JOIN CLIENTE ON ORDEMSERVICO.FK_CODCLIENTE = CLIENTE.CODCLIENTE\n"
                + "INNER JOIN STATUS ON ORDEMSERVICO.CODSTATUS = STATUS.CODSTATUS\n"
                + "INNER JOIN PESSOA ON ORDEMSERVICO.RESPONSAVEL = PESSOA.CODPESSOA\n"
                + "WHERE ORDEMSERVICO.DATAENTREGA BETWEEN ('"+deInicio+"') AND ('"+ateInicio+"')\n"
                + "AND ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL = TRUE\n"
                + "AND ORDEMSERVICO.CODTIPOOS = 21\n"
                + "AND ORDEMSERVICO.CODSTATUS = 11";
        
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
        ArrayList<OrdemServico> tarefas = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            OrdemServico ordemServico = new OrdemServico();
            Projeto projeto = new Projeto();
            Adicional adicional = new Adicional();
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            Venda venda = new Venda();
            Status status = new Status();
            Pessoa responsavel = new Pessoa();
            ordemServico.setPrincipal(rs.getBoolean("ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL"));
            projeto.setId(rs.getInt("ORDEMSERVICO.ID_PROJETO"));
            ordemServico.setProjeto(projeto);
            adicional.setNumero(rs.getInt("ADICIONAIS.NUMERO"));
            ordemServico.setAdicional(adicional);
            cliente.setNomeFantasia(rs.getString("CLIENTE.NOMEFANTASIA"));
            ordemServico.setCliente(cliente);
            ordemServico.setNome(rs.getString("ORDEMSERVICO.NOME"));
            venda.setValorFaturamentoDireto(rs.getDouble("ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDIRETO"));
            venda.setValorFaturamentoDolphin(rs.getDouble("ORDEMSERVICO.VALORFATDOLPHIN"));
            venda.setValorComissao(rs.getDouble("ORDEMSERVICO.VALOR_COMISSAO"));
            ordemServico.setPrioridade(rs.getInt("ORDEMSERVICO.PRIORIDADE"));
            status.setNome(rs.getString("STATUS.NOME"));
            ordemServico.setStatus(status);
            if (rs.getTimestamp("ORDEMSERVICO.DATASOLICITACAO") != null) {
                ordemServico.setDataSolicitacao(rs.getDate("ORDEMSERVICO.DATASOLICITACAO").toLocalDate());
            }
            if (rs.getTimestamp("ORDEMSERVICO.DATAINICIO") != null) {
                ordemServico.setDataSolicitacao(rs.getDate("ORDEMSERVICO.DATASOLICITACAO").toLocalDate());
            }
            if (rs.getTimestamp("ORDEMSERVICO.DATAPREVENTREGA") != null) {
                ordemServico.setDataPrevEntrega(rs.getDate("ORDEMSERVICO.DATAPREVENTREGA").toLocalDate());
            }
            if (rs.getTimestamp("ORDEMSERVICO.DATAENTREGA") != null) {
                ordemServico.setDataEntrega(rs.getDate("ORDEMSERVICO.DATAENTREGA").toLocalDate());
            }
            responsavel.setNome(rs.getString("PESSOA.NOME"));
            ordemServico.setResponsavel(responsavel);
            
            tarefas.add(ordemServico);
        }
        return tarefas;
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new SQLException("Erro ao buscar registros do relatório! " + se.getMessage());
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas coisas.

1. Se quer realizar uma consulta sem risco de ataque de injeção de SQL, evite concatenar strings. E sempre use PreparedStatement.
2. O erro me parece claro. Coluna ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL não encontrada. Você informou uma condição PRINCIPAL = TRUE em um select feito na tabela ORDEMSERVICO. Então o banco intuiu que essa coluna existe nessa tabela. Se essa coluna fica em outra tabela, então precisa informar o nome completo, por exemplo PROJETOS.PRINCIPAL = TRUE.

Comment: Eu tenho certeza absoluta de que a coluna PRINCIPAL pertence à tabela ORDEMSERVICO, até porque o código SQL funciona no Workbench.

Comment: Pode então tentar usar alias, exemplo: `ORDEMSERVICO.PRINCIPAL AS PRINCIPAL` e referenciar a coluna por `PRINCIPAL` em outros lugares. Pois observando melhor, talvez o problema esteja na linha `ordemServico.setPrincipal(...);`.

Comment: Funcionou mas eu tive que apelidar todas as colunas